# Allow only specific domain names to register in Rails App (Devise gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have read about similar case here: [Validation specific email specific domain devise 3 ruby on rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082578/validation-specific-email-specific-domain-devise-3-ruby-on-rails-4)

However, it's only one email domain (e.x. example.com). What I want is to alloww some email domains that I have (ex. domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com, etc.). How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
APPROVED_DOMAINS = ["domain_one.com", "domain2.com"]
* or you can load this from somewhere else

validates :email, presence: true, if: :domain_check

def domain_check
  unless APPROVED_DOMAINS.any? { |word| email.end_with?(word)}
    errors.add(:email, "is not from a valid domain")
  end
end
```

Comment: I would add an additional validation like
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/35519515/595152 did, because this means validate presence of email only when domain is correct

Comment: I love this solution. Because I could add as many domains as I like. Beside validation is fantastic to have, I don't know if validation for many domains could be done.!!!

Answer (score 7):

you can add the following code in your model

```
  validate :email_domain

  def email_domain
    domain = email.split("@").last
    if !email.blank?
      errors.add(:email, "Invalid Domain") if domain != "gmail.com"
    end
  end
```

You can add as many domain you want to allow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it takes too many lines if you put it in the model like that. Is it possible to set a variable and then get the email domain lists in another file or maybe in the bottom of the model file? If yes, then how the code will looks like?

Comment: You can define a array of domains that you want to allow and check that array includes the domain of the given email or not

Answer (score 3):

I use the code by Pavan in other thread ([Allow only specific emails to register in Rails app (Devise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090205/allow-only-specific-emails-to-register-in-rails-app-devise)) and it's working.

To allow specific email, I use these code to my user model:

```
validates :email, format: { with: /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@xyz\.com\z/, message: "must be a xyz.com account" }
```