# Pre-authorization in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm writing a portal that will be open only to people who work at my company.  I'm using the Devise framework to handle authentication, but there's a requirement that only employees should be able to sign up.  HR will issue each employee a randomly generated access code, and then that employee will use his or her employee number and access code to gain initial access to the site.  Once the user has been authenticated, functionality for completing the sign up can can be handled by Devise.

We looked into devise_invitable but decided not to use it because we don't want to collect email addresses from employees.

I have implemented this by creating a custom authorizations view and controller to check the employee number/access code combination.  Here's what I've done:

In the custom controller, if the employee number and access code combination is correct, set an authentication token in a tokens table, set a matching token in the user's session, and redirect flow to the registrations/new method of Devise.  Here's some pseudocode:

```
def check_authorization
  if employee number and code are correct
    token = SecureRandom.base58(36)
    set database value to token
    session[:authentication_token] = token
    redirect_to devise_new_user_registration_path
  else
    render 'authorize'
  end
end
```

In the registrations controller of Devise, check for a session token that matches one in the database, if not found redirect flow to my custom authorization controller.  I also wrote a helper method to clean up authorizations once control has passed to Devise.  I made changes to the new and create methods and left everything else as is.  More pseudocode:

```
def new
  if( get_authorization( session[:ot_authorization_token] ) == nil )
    redirect_to custom_authorization_path
  else
    super
  end
end
def create
  authorization = get_authorization( session[:ot_authorization_token] )
  if( authorization == nil )
    redirect_to custom_authorization_path
  else
    super do |authorization|
      clean_up( authorization )
    end
  end
end
```

Will this work?  Am I missing anything?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but wouldn't it be easier to just only allow people with a certain domain name to sign up?  And then you could send an email confirmation to confirm?  Maybe something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082578/validation-specific-email-specific-domain-devise-3-ruby-on-rails-4 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work.  People will be signing in from many domains, most of them not ours.  I appreciate the suggestion, though.